# How to animate JavaFX background gradient with light colors

Tags: javafx, concurrency

I am looking for the solution for light color background gradient animation. I have looked into other examples with KeyFrames and was unable to do it by myself.

So I made a primitive version of what I need:

```
boolean rbottomforward = true;
boolean gbottomforward = true;
boolean bbottomforward = true;
int redbottom = 171;
int greenbottom = 186;
int bluebottom = 171;

boolean rtopforward = true;
boolean gtopforward = true;
boolean btopforward = true;
int redtop = 255;
int greentop = 255;
int bluetop = 255;

@Override
protected Void call() throws Exception {
    Timeline backgroundAnimator = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), event -> {
        backgroundPane.getStylesheets().clear();
        backgroundPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to top, "+ randomBottomColor()+", "+randomTopColor()+");");

    }));
    backgroundAnimator.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    backgroundAnimator.play();
    return null;
}

private String randomBottomColor() {
    greenbottom = newBottomGreen();
    redbottom = newBottomRed();
    bluebottom = newBottomBlue();
    return String.format("rgb(%d,%d,%d)", redbottom, greenbottom, bluebottom);
}

private int newBottomGreen() {
    if(greenbottom <255 && greenbottom >155){
        if(gbottomforward)
greenbottom +=getRandomNumber();
        else
greenbottom -=getRandomNumber();
    } else if(greenbottom >=255) {
        gbottomforward=false;
        greenbottom -=getRandomNumber();
    } else {
        gbottomforward=true;
        greenbottom +=getRandomNumber();
    }
    return greenbottom;
}

private int getRandomNumber() {
    int r = (int) (Math.random() * (3 - 1)) + 1;
    return r;
}

private int newBottomRed() {
    if(redbottom <255 && redbottom >155){
        if(rbottomforward)
redbottom +=getRandomNumber();
        else
redbottom -=getRandomNumber();
    } else if(redbottom >=255) {
        rbottomforward=false;
        redbottom -=getRandomNumber();
    } else {
        rbottomforward=true;
        redbottom +=getRandomNumber();
    }
    return redbottom;
}

private int newBottomBlue() {
    if(bluebottom <255 && bluebottom >155){
        if(bbottomforward)
bluebottom +=getRandomNumber();
        else
bluebottom -=getRandomNumber();
    } else if(bluebottom >=255) {
        bbottomforward=false;
        bluebottom -=getRandomNumber();
    } else{
        bbottomforward=true;
        bluebottom +=getRandomNumber();
    }
    return bluebottom;
}
private String randomTopColor() {
    greentop = newTopGreen();
    redtop = newTopRed();
    bluetop = newTopBlue();
    return String.format("rgb(%d,%d,%d)", redtop, greentop, bluetop);
}

private int newTopGreen() {
    if(greentop <255 && greentop >155){
        if(gtopforward)
greentop +=getRandomNumber();
        else
greentop -=getRandomNumber();
    } else if(greentop >=255) {
        gtopforward=false;
        greentop -=getRandomNumber();
    } else {
        gtopforward=true;
        greentop +=getRandomNumber();
    }
    return greentop;
}

private int newTopRed() {
    if(redtop <255 && redtop >155){
        if(rtopforward)
redtop +=getRandomNumber();
        else
redtop -=getRandomNumber();
    } else if(redtop >=255) {
        rtopforward=false;
        redtop -=getRandomNumber();
    } else {
        rtopforward=true;
        redtop +=getRandomNumber();
    }
    return redtop;
}

private int newTopBlue() {
    if(bluetop <255 && bluetop >155){
        if(btopforward)
bluetop +=getRandomNumber();
        else
bluetop -=getRandomNumber();
    } else if(bluetop >=255) {
        btopforward=false;
        bluetop -=getRandomNumber();
    } else{
        btopforward=true;
        bluetop +=getRandomNumber();
    }
    return bluetop;
}
```

This is a bit overkill. Can anyone help me convert this to a more advanced level code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really not much you can do about this but reduce the repetition in code. (You won't be able to interpolate anything, since on every update the next color is chosen at random.)

You should use the same code for all the color channels:

```
/**
 * Class containing logic for a single color channel.
 */
private class AnimatedChannel {
    private boolean increment = true;
    private int value;

    AnimatedChannel(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * Changes channel by random amount in [1, 3] keeping it in range [155, 255] 
     */
    private void update() {
        int delta = getRandomNumber();
        if (increment) {
            value += delta;
            if (value > 0xFF) {
                value = (2 * 0xFF) - value; // v = max - (v - max)
                increment = false;
            }
        } else {
            value -= delta;
            if (value < 155) {
                value = (2 * 155) - value; // v = min + (min - v)
                increment = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

private final Random random = new Random();

private int getRandomNumber() {
    return random.nextInt(3 - 1) + 1;
}

private final AnimatedChannel bottomRed = new AnimatedChannel(171);
private final AnimatedChannel bottomGreen = new AnimatedChannel(186);
private final AnimatedChannel bottomBlue = new AnimatedChannel(171);

private final AnimatedChannel topRed = new AnimatedChannel(0xFF);
private final AnimatedChannel topGreen = new AnimatedChannel(0xFF);
private final AnimatedChannel topBlue = new AnimatedChannel(0xFF);

private final AnimatedChannel[] channels = new AnimatedChannel[] {
    bottomRed,
    bottomGreen,
    bottomBlue,
    topRed,
    topGreen,
    topBlue
};

@Override
protected Void call() throws Exception {
    Timeline backgroundAnimator = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), event -> {
        for (AnimatedChannel channel : channels) {
            channel.update();
        }
        backgroundPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(
            new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,
                new Stop(0, channelsToColor(topRed, topGreen, topBlue)),
                new Stop(1, channelsToColor(bottomRed, bottomGreen, bottomBlue))),
            CornerRadii.EMPTY,
            Insets.EMPTY)));
    }));
    backgroundAnimator.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    backgroundAnimator.play();
    return null;
}

private static Color channelsToColor(AnimatedChannel red, AnimatedChannel green, AnimatedChannel blue) {
    return Color.rgb(red.value, green.value, blue.value);
}
```

This code is not that much shorter than your code, but it's easier to maintain. If you want to modify the logic for updating the channels, you only need to adjust 1 method instead of 6 methods. Also it relieves JavaFX of the burden of parsing the inline CSS on every update.

**Note:**

You seem to be extending `Task<Void>` or some similar concurrency-related class. This is not really necessary, since `Timeline.play` is not a long running operation but simply triggers repeated execution of logic (in this case the `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`) on the application thread at a later time.

Comment: Thanks..  error at `value = (2 * 0xFF) - channel.value;`. Changed to `value = (2 * 0xFF) - value;`